# SCSS and Browser loading is not working with gulpfile.js

Tags: wordpress, sass, gulp

I have a WordPress theme in the wp-content directory which name is **wonaco**. In this folder, I have this gulpfile.js file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var pipeline = require('readable-stream').pipeline;

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('wanoca/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(cssnano())
        // concat will combine all files declared in your "src"
        .pipe(concat('main.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('wanoca/assets/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }))
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function(done) {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'wanoca'
        },
    });
    done();
})

gulp.task('compress', function() {
    return pipeline(
        gulp.src('wanoca/js/*.js'),
        uglify(),
        gulp.dest('wanoca/assets/js')
    );
});

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('browserSync', 'sass', 'compress', function() {
    gulp.watch('wanoca/scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
    gulp.watch('wanoca/js/*.js', gulp.series('compress'));
    gulp.watch("wanoca/**/*.html", { events: 'all' }, function(cb) {
        browserSync.reload();
        cb();
    });
    gulp.watch('wanoca/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
}));
```

**My theme folder structure is like that:**

```
assets
inc
js
languages
node_modules
page_templates
scss
template-parts
.gitignore
all WordPress files...
```

I am trying to compile the **scss** and **js** folder code to **assets/css** and **assets/js**

But using my current gulpfile.js file code **it's not watching** any scss changes and **not loading the changes to the browser** with the correct URL.

*correct URL is http://localhost/wanoca-wp/*

Can you guys tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: I fixed the `scss` compile issues by removing the `wonaco` folder name from `gulpfile.js` file but how can I load the changes on the localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Your node, package, and gulp files have to be outside the main wp app folder, ie.